# Passwd via PAM only work for LDAP

Tags: linux, debian, ldap, pam, passwd

Now I'v got a working setup using PAM+LDAP over SSL but I can only passwd users in the ldap tree, any idea about how to be able to passwd every users ?

Here are some conf files :
`/etc/pam.d/common-password` :

```
password   optional     pam_unix.so nullok obscure try_first_pass
password   sufficient   pam_ldap.so ignore_unknown_user
password   required     pam_deny.so
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` :

```
passwd:         compat ldap
group:          compat ldap
shadow:         compat ldap

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Any idea ?

Note : I'm running Debian Lenny on every system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove

```
password required pam_deny.so
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very very much, that's perfect now !